# jQuery Draggable does not move the caret position in the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jQuery draggable and it is working fine for the scenarios that are needed. One missing thing is that when I drag my element in the text the cursor does not move along the drag element movement.
For example :- I have a simple use case as

```
<div id="filterBar" contenteditable="true">This contains some text</div>
```

is the drop container

```
<span id="dragOsversion">OSVersion=19.1, 19.2</span>
```

is the drag element

```
$.find("#dragOsversion").draggable({helper: 'clone'});
```

is the instantiation of dragOsversion span to act as a draggable element

---

Now when I drag the span over the filterBar div, the cursor does not move along :(

---

This feature is natively present in HTML5 draggable and works fine with the -img- and -a- tags.
for example

```
<a id="dragOsversion" href="#" draggable="true">OSVersion=19.1, 19.2</a>
```

is the drag element

Above will move the cursor as the  element is moved over the filterBar.

---

https://jsfiddle.net/VidushiGupta/7warczfy/

is the example showcasing the 2 behaviors

Would any one have an idea how to move along the cursor in text area, when dropping jQuery helper element.

I tried to google a lot on same, but did not find any pointers to even proceed.

---

I tried some hacks like trying to wrap the element that is draggable by jQuery with in -a- tag which has native draggable. But the jQuery draggable overrides the native behavior and the caret position has no effect while dragging the elements.

Any help / suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a snippet or jsfiddle that shows your issue?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/VidushiGupta/7warczfy/

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Weft - I am testing Chrome currently - and it is working with 'native HTML' but not with jQuery draggable example. I have included both the examples in there for comparison.